# How to pin to Start Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Oxygen and the default directory of the installation is: `C:\Users\Robert Gomez\eclipse\java-oxygen`

I did: `Right click > Pin to Start`

and I got:

[image]

why?, it doesn't open either.

I did a clean installation of Windows, before this, it was working great.

Any solution?.

(I don't want to pin Eclipse to taskbar, I want it on Start)

Answer (score 1):

Start it from the normal shortcut on your desktop (or wherever).  Once it is loaded, then right-click the icon in the taskbar and select pin to taskbar from there.

If that doesn't work, run a second copy of eclipse while the first one is still running, and do the same right-click pin option on that one.  I'm not sure exactly why that works, but it does.

Comment: I don't want to pin Eclipse to taskbar, I want it on Start.

Comment: Ah, I did not take note of the difference, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is probably too late, but here is my answer.

You can try following:

1. Create shortcut to eclipse.exe
2. Copy the shortcut to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
3. Open the Start and shortcut to eclipse will be displayed on top
4. Pin the shortcut to Start